# What are $\mu$ and $\nu$ in $g_{\mu\nu}$ metric?

Tags: soft-question, metric-tensor, notation

What are $\mu$ and $\nu$ in $g_{\mu\nu}$ metric?

Consider the metric $g_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 &0 \\ 
0 & r^2 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & r^2\sin^2\theta
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: The $\mu$ and $\nu$ are indices. For example, the first diagonal entry of the metric is $g_{00}$ since it is located in the $0$th row and $0$th column.

Answer (score 7):

Those Greek letters are indices indexing the components of $g$. Generally if one expresses a rank-2 tensor like $g$ as a matrix, the first index indexes the rows, the second the columns. In your example, we have $g_{rr} \equiv g_{11} = 1$, $g_{\theta\theta} \equiv g_{22} = r^2$, $g_{r\theta} \equiv g_{12} = 0$, etc.

As you can see, we sometimes use numbers to refer to specific indices, and sometimes letters related to the coordinate system in play. When you have not just a metric for space but one for space*time*, $0$ is frequently used to index the time component.

Often if we use Latin letters $i,j,\ldots$ as free indices we mean "this index is spatial, not temporal." Of course some authors reverse the roles of Greek and Latin here, just to keep you on your toes.

---

More pedantically, "$g_{\mu\nu}$" is an indeterminate component of $g$, whereas the matrix you wrote is the collection of all components in some understood basis. It would probably be more proper to either write
$$ g \stackrel{\mathcal{B}}{\longrightarrow}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2 \sin^2\!\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(the tensor as expressed in some basis $\mathcal{B}$, which happens to be the standard $(r,\theta,\phi)$ of spherical coordinates in our case, is represented by the matrix), or
$$ (g_{\mu\nu})_{\mu,\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2 \sin^2\!\theta
\end{pmatrix} $$
(the matrix of values $g_{\mu\nu}$, ranging over indices $\mu$ and $\nu$, is equal to the matrix, where $\mathcal{B}$ is understood). But these are both rather overbearing notation, and so are rarely used.

Answer (score 2):

$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}g_{00}&g_{01}&g_{02}\\g_{10}&g_{11}&g_{12}\\g_{20}&g_{21}&g_{22}\end{pmatrix}$$
$\mu,\nu=0,\ldots,N$ are the matrix indices of the metric (and of tensors in general) in $N+1$ dimensions.